# C# ArrayList Print and sum values

Tags: c#, arraylist, printing, sum

I have the following code, the user enter values to the arraylist, than i am trying to print the array value (if the user add 999) and sum the values of the arraylist
i must use arraylist because that is what i was asked to do (so please don't suggest to use another kind of array)

```
        ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
        int num1 = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while (num1 != 999)
        {
            num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            myArray.Add(num1);
            foreach (int i in myArray)
            {
                sum = sum + i;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(myArray);
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

The problem is, when i am trying to prin the arraylist values it print instead the following text:
System.Collections.ArrayList

And instead of printing the sum of all values (for example the values are 1,2,3) he print the sum 1015 instead of 6.

Will appreciate any help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit to make it work.

```
ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
int num1 = 0;
int sum = 0;
while (true)
{
    num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (num1 == 999) break; //Don't add 999 to list.
    myArray.Add(num1);
}

//OR simply sum = myArray.Cast<int>().Sum();
foreach (int i in myArray)
{
    sum = sum + i;
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",myArray.Cast<int>()));
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

PS: Instead of `ArrayList` use `List<int>`

Comment: But is promoting poor practice.  while(true) is awful - and is almost never justified.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this code.

First, num1 is being added to the array before it is checked.  So, the last value of 999 is added to the array, then the while loop terminates after it is added.  Whenever possible / practical, I make use of for loops to prevent bugs like this.  Seeing `while(true)`- shown in another answer, makes my skin crawl.  It is not good practice at all.

```
for(int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); num1 != 999; num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
{
    myArray.Add(num1);
}
```

Second, you are iterating through myArray within the while loop.  In the case you provided, your sum actually ends up being 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 999.

As for printing, the previous poster is correct.  Iterate through myArray in order to print each value, or use `String.Join` as shown in another post.

Something else - using int.Parse is typically not a good idea - especially when user input is involved.  Have a look at int.TryParse instead.

Answer (score -3):

`myArray` is of type ArrayList. If you want to print each item in the list then you have to access each item and print it individually.

You did this when you were summing the array items, so just add a `Write` statement there, and move this out of your `while` block:

```
foreach (int i in myArray)
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
    sum = sum + i;
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

---

Alternately, you can just use a `join` in your original WriteLine statement:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",myArray.Cast<int>()));
```

instead of

```
Console.WriteLine(myArray);
```

Comment: Hi, This is still not works... this is the result of your edit code: 1, 1 2, 1 2 3... every time i want to enter a number the new line shows the number i entered before with the new number i edd now. i want it to print all values only in the end... and still have the problem after 999, it prints System.Collections.ArrayList

Comment: You need to move your `foreach` statement out of your `while` statement.